# Can I add the PluralizingTableNameConvention to the EF powertools?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am currently using the Entity Framework Powertools (beta 4) to generate my POCO classes from an existing db, which has upwards of 800 tables.

Whilst this is awesome, and saving me a **lot** of time, I noticed that the tool is pluralizing my POCO classes, or de-pluralizing them. Some of our tables are pluralized, and others are not, so to keep things simple, I want the POCO's to match the underlying db table names. In my main DbContext, I have the  `PluralizingTableNameConvention` and `PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention` removed in the `OnModelCreating()` method call, so the application is fine.

My question is whether this configuration can be re-created in the EF Powertools so that the classes come out correctly, and do not require me retrofitting the class names etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this cant be done, however I have download the EF Powertools code from [Codeplex](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), and built the tools manually. I then created my own implementation of the `PluralizationService` in which I did not pluralize anything.

Job done.